# How can we make a loop with chronicle statement in C++?

Tags: c++

I was wondering how we could make a loop (a while-loop, for example) where the statement inside the while-loop be time-based.

To be more clear, for example I would like to make a while-loop which I will enter every 10 seconds.

A pseudocode would be like this:

```
while (10 seconds have passed)
{
    //do Something
}
```

So, how could make the above pseudocode real? (I hope having been clear)

Comment: Check what you could gain from `std::chrono` and `std::thread`.

Comment: Does this while loop execute every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 5):

I generally use something like this:

```
// for an easier life
using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

// set the baseline time
auto timeout = clock::now();

for(;;)
{
    // (re)set timer
    timeout += std::chrono::seconds(10);

    // sleep until time has elapsed
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(timeout);

    // do something useful (like print the time)
    auto timer = std::time(0);
    std::cout << "loop: " << std::ctime(&timer) << '\n';
}
```

By using `std::this_thread::sleep_until()` the loop doesn't consume `CPU` time while it is waiting for the `10` seconds to elapse.

This can be wrapped up in a neat little class like this:

```
class wait_timer
{
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    clock::duration time_to_wait;
    clock::time_point timeout = clock::now();

public:
    wait_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds ms)
    : time_to_wait(ms), timeout(clock::now()) {}

    void wait()
    {
        timeout += time_to_wait; // (re)set timer
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(timeout);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // create it outside the loop so it doesn't
    // loose track of time every iteration
    wait_timer wt(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    for(;;)
    {
        wt.wait();

        // do something useful (like print the time)
        auto timer = std::time(0);
        std::cout << "loop: " << std::ctime(&timer) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<time.h>` header file and use the internal clock to measure if 10 seconds have passed or not

```
clock_t t;

while (1) {    // This loop runs exactly once every 10 seconds
    t = clock();    // Reset clock

    // Do something in this loop

    while ((double)(clock()-t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC < 10);    // Wait if 10 seconds havent passed

}
```

This would fail if your computation inside the while loop takes more than 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::this_thread::sleep_for`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    while (1) {
        // some code

        this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
    }
}
```