# How yo build a timer in C++11 that will call a method from an instanciated object

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I am instanting an object A in the main.

One of its method f consists in getting inputs from a database, computing some values and then updating (write) a database.

I want to call f every x minutes. Let's say f needs y seconds to process.

How can i do that safely for both linux and windows plateform?
Of course if the process is killed outside it should not leave the database in an unknown state.
Thanks

Comment: This may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240834/how-can-we-make-a-loop-with-chronicle-statement-in-c/37241412#37241412

Comment: and also this may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059115/c11-thread-class-how-to-use-a-class-member-function/21239387#21239387

Comment: ... also: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47347/follow-up-timer-utilizing-stdfuture

Comment: could it be stopped by kill 15 or kill 9 on unix or Ctrl +c on windows ? Thanks