# accurate sampling in c++

Tags: c++, sampling, c++-chrono

I want to sample values I get from a gpio 4000 times per second, currently I do something like that:

```
std::vector<int> sample_a_chunk(unsigned int rate, unsigned int block_size_in_seconds) {
    std::vector<std::int> data;
    constexpr unsigned int times = rate * block_size_in_seconds;
    constexpr unsigned int delay = 1000000 / rate; // microseconds
    for (int j=0; j<times; j++) {
      data.emplace_back(/* read the value from the gpio */);
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(delay));
    }
    return data;
}
```

yet according to the reference sleep_for is guaranteed to wait for **at least** the specified amount of time.

How can I have my system wait for the *exact* amount of time, or at least achieve the best possible accuracy?
How can I be sure of the time resolution of my system?

Comment: You would need to use operating system services to do what you ask.

Comment: there is no way to sleep an "exact" amount of time.   That's not how computers work.   Even an RTOS doesn't guarantee exact sleeps.  Why don't you see how good what you already have is before you spend time trying to make it "better" when you don't know how good is good enough.

Comment: Operating system shmoperating system. You want exact time, you need a deterministic system, and that writes out anything with threads and interrupts. Aim for good enough time. Make sure you have timer resolution 5-10 times that of what you need and low enough context switch latency to ensure you never over sleep by enough to care.

Comment: @xaxxon because this program will run in a system that I can only access certain days per week only - I can't test it at the moment and I'd like to be as well prepared as possible when next access the system

Comment: If you want to avoid time drift use absolute timing (`wait_until`), this may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240834/how-can-we-make-a-loop-with-chronicle-statement-in-c/37241412#37241412

Comment: Efficient 4 kHz sampling? Sounds like a task best handled by a sound card. They typically can buffer quite a few readings, have little jitter, and don't need much CPU per sample.

Comment: @MSalters 's comment about off-loading the acquisition responsibility   is great, and raises an unasked sub-question: Is this PC hardware or an embedded device? On the PC definitely offload the job to better suited hardware if possible. On an embedded device there may be timer interrupt games that you can play.

Comment: It's not physically possible on a conventional (clocked) processor.  It does sound (ha!) like you need to offload this to specialized hardware, from which you can read in processor timescales.

Comment: @user4581301 no it's not PC hardware - it's for a single-board computer with no audio-input, I'm trying to read analogue data over SPI through a MPC3008 chip.

Comment: Read through the data sheet. Some A/Ds take in a clock pulse and can be programmed to schedule their own sampling. and notify you when data is ready to be read.Give them a reliable clock signal and your job becomes dead easy: See interrupt, read data, rinse, repeat. A quick read through the MPC3008 datasheet doesn't show any signs of this ability, so you have to count on the processor to do the timing. Your SBC may have a a little offload MCU for work like this. The TI Sitara for example has the "PRU" cores built in for precisely this sort of work. I still prefer a smarter A/D though.

Comment: @user4581301 could you recommend such a smarter A/D with that I could read using SPI ? thanks.

Comment: Been a while since I've worked a 10 bit system that wasn't built into the CPU. TI ADC1005 comes to mind.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best you can probably achieve is to use *absolute* timing so as to avoid drift.

Something like this:

```
std::vector<int> sample_a_chunk(unsigned int rate,
    unsigned int block_size_in_seconds)
{
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    std::vector<int> data;

    const auto times = rate * block_size_in_seconds;
    const auto delay = std::chrono::microseconds{1000000 / rate};

    auto next_sample = clock::now() + delay;

    for(int j = 0; j < times; j++)
    {
        data.emplace_back(/* read the value from the gpio */);

        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_sample);

        next_sample += delay; // don't refer back to clock, stay absolute
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You beat me by 4min with an answer virtually identical to my own (+1).  Nitpicks:  I would use `steady_clock` instead of `high_resolution_clock`.  On gcc `high_resolution_clock` is `system_clock` which might get adjusted.  Also I don't think `sleep_until` can return early, so I didn't bother with a loop to check that.  But the big picture item is to use `sleep_until` to eliminate the drift, which you got spot on! :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant I started with steady_clock because its fast enough on my system but then I saw *microseconds* and wondered if small devices clocks might differ...? so I went with *high_resolution*. I'll add a note.

Comment: No, I changed it to *steady* after all. Its accurate timings that is required.

Comment: @HowardHinnant On my Linux system the `sleep_until` breaks early whenever the process receives a signal. That's why I do the loop.

Comment: I'm currently recommending not to use `high_resolution_clock`: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M&t=48m0s which I realize is controversial advice.

Comment: But `condition_variable`s are allowed to return spuriously, timed or not.  I don't believe the same is true for `sleep_until`, even if a `condition_variable` is part of its implementation.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm wondering if a bug report is needed, and if it should go to gcc, or to the std::committee...

Comment: @HowardHinnant I can't reproduce it now, but I'm pretty sure I have upgraded my `GCC` since I last made a test case for this.

Comment: Well if you manage to repro it again, I'm counting on you to make noise.  I think it best not to bother the end user with that loop.

Comment: @HowardHinnant I removed it from the example because it was evidently a bug and we don't want to be coding for *just in case* the compiler has a bug. Originally I assumed it was an `OS` thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [boost::asio::deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html).

```
#include <vector>

#define BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY 1
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

std::vector<int> sample_a_chunk(unsigned int rate, unsigned int block_size_in_seconds) {
  std::vector<int> data;
  const unsigned int times = rate * block_size_in_seconds;
  auto expiration_time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
  const auto delay = boost::posix_time::microseconds(1000000/rate);
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io);

  for (unsigned int j=0; j < times; j++) {
    expiration_time += delay;
    data.emplace_back(/* read the value from the gpio */);
    t.expires_at(expiration_time);
    t.wait();
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Link only answers are useless answers as soon as the links rot. `boost::asio::deadline_timer` link is OK because anyone can look that up, but I recommend expanding the answer to summarize the contents of the tutorials.

Comment: Thanks @user4581301. I've replaced the links with sample code.