# How to use chrono sleep until without lag?

Tags: c++, delay, sleep, c++-chrono, aruco

I am just a starter in c++, i need to draw object on existing four markers with a delay between each marker and the other, i tried to use Chrono_ sleep_until, but it causes my program to lag, and even the object is instantly appearing and disappearing onsecond marker, i know that there is something wrong but can not guess what it may be, any help?

```
std::vector<int> ids;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > corners;
    cv::aruco::detectMarkers(image, marker_dict, corners, ids);

    // Draw markers using opencv tool
    cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(mid, corners, ids);

    // Draw markers custom
    for (size_t i = 0; i < corners.size(); ++i)
    {

        // Convert to integer ponits
        int num = static_cast<int>(corners[i].size());
        std::vector<cv::Point> points;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < corners[i].size(); ++j)
            points.push_back(cv::Point(static_cast<int>(corners[i][j].x), static_cast<int>(corners[i][j].y)));
        const cv::Point* pts = &(points[0]);


        // Draw


        
        if (ids.at(i) == 32) {
            cv::fillPoly(right, &pts, &num, 1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));

        }
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(2);
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(timePoint);
    
    
            if (ids.at(i) == 45) {
            
                cv::fillPoly(right, &pts, &num, 1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
                break;
            
        
            }
```

Comment: `sleep_until` only works accurately when you define the end time before the loop and increment it within the loop - otherwise the time will drift. Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987806/accurate-sampling-in-c/39988284#39988284

Comment: @Galik I did so, and there is no lag anymore, but the second marker which has id 45, does not wait for the defined time, and appear, disappear blinking repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

sleep is great for PoCs and quick fixes for small problems, but for most serious projects you may want to consider using a timer, wait until the timer hits your delay and then continue.  Then the rest of your code is still executing and no thread is sleeping.

This is an over-simplified solution just to give you the concept, it will call DrawB() 1 second after calling DrawA() without sleeping

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, now;
std::chrono::milliseconds duration;

bool bDoDrawA = true;
bool bDoDrawB = false;

void DrawA()
{
    std::cout << "DrawA()" << std::endl;

    bDoDrawB = true;
    bDoDrawA = false;
}

void DrawB()
{
    std::cout << "DrawB()" << std::endl;

    bDoDrawB = false;
    bDoDrawA = true;
    start = Clock::now();
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (bDoDrawA)
        {
            DrawA();
        }
        
        if (bDoDrawB)
        {
            now = Clock::now();
            duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - start);

            if (duration.count() >= 2000)
            {
                DrawB();
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```